# Automapper - setting a custom type convertor for a member

Tags: c#, automapper

Lets have two classes

```
public class Source
{
     public string Prop1 {get;set;}
}

public class Dest
{
     public float Prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

How to set a custom type convertor for `Prop1` property ?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ConvertUsing](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home) as described in the docs. For that you need to define a Converter. Or you can define the mapping:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Prop1,
                src => src.MapFrom(m => float.Parse(m.Prop1, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            ));
        Source sourceObject = new Source() { Prop1 = "1.5" };
        Dest destination = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(sourceObject);
        Console.WriteLine("value {0}", destination.Prop1);
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public float Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No I can't. ConvertUsing takes a value of type ITypeConverter<Source, Dest>.

Comment: ConvertUsing takes any Func<Source, Dest>, not just an implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be better just to map the object manually.

about custom mapping you can read [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/06/automapper-feature-custom-type-converters/)